# Why does (-2.4492935982947064e-16).toFixed(5) equal "-0.00000"?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision, tofixed

Given this code:

```
const value = 1;
Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * value).toFixed(5);
```

Why does this return `"-0.00000"`, when the value before `.toFixed(5)` is `-2.4492935982947064e-16`?

Comment: Because the number is in scientific notation.

Comment: Do you know what exponential notation is? (That e-16 at the end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number is in scientific notation.

The e-16 means that there are 16 0's to the left of the number.

```
-2.4492935982947064e-16
```

is really

```
-0.00000000000000024492935982947064
```

When you run toFixed(5), you end up with 5 decimal places, which are all 0's.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thank you. I should of course have checked the real value first _facepalm_

Answer (score 0):

The number you presented `-2.4492935982947064e-16` is in scientific notation. That number would be equivalent to `-2.4492935982947064 × 10^-16` which would be exactly `-0.00000000000000024492935982947064` after expanding it.

Answer (score 0):

`-2.4492935982947064e-16` is `-2.4492935982947064 * Math.pow(10,-16)`, so 5 places after decimal point is not enough to see something different than 0

```js
const value = 1;
let result = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * value);
console.log(result)
console.log(result.toFixed(20))
console.log(result.toFixed(5))
```